# Isotope using 3 columns but should be 4

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

Isotope was working correctly, now when you click a category such as 'food' it shows in 3 columns instead of 4. 
See here: http://www.topshops.com.au/store_listings_generic.html
I get a javascript error see below. 
Now the weird thing is the same files put into a folder called 'test' work perfect please see here: http://www.kinectwebdesign.com/test/store_listings_generic.html 
But if I change the name of the 'test' folder to the www.topshops.com.au it goes wonky again.

```
2yui-min.js:12 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), not all, not all, (min-resolution: 192dpi)
yui-min.js:12 Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, 
not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. 
In media query expression: (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)

jquery.isotope.min.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Comment: I see it correct, in 4 columns, and i play a lot with the effects and transitions and still seeing 4 columns. Maybe you have something cached?

I'm on Chrome, Ubuntu if that helps..

I see the warning you comment but still no problem at all.

Comment: So bizarre, I cleared the browser cache and my host says it looks ok from their end. I am using chrome which is where it looks odd. Oddly enough in mozilla looks  good. Thanks for letting me know it looks ok. I just made some adjustments and still looks odd in chrome. Doing my head in. Thanks Kangcor.

Comment: Can you grab the generated css in your chrome and compare with the correct one in firefox? Maybe are little differences that can tell us what the problem is

Comment: I feel it could be css also. How do I grab the css from browser? I can inspect element is that what you mean?

Comment: I went to w3c validator and got this when I enter the store listings page. I got the following unexpected response when trying to retrieve <http://www.topshops.com.au/store_listings.html>:
500 Internal Server Error
If you made recent changes to your domain name (DNS) configuration, you may also want to check that your domain records are correct, or ask your hosting company to do so.
You can choose to validate the received error document for example if the URL intentionally points to one (there is also a "Validate error pages" option in the options view for this purpose).